# Insert Excel row with normal height

Tags: c#, excel, excel-addins

This is my C# code to insert rows into an Excel worksheet:

```
for (var j = 0; j < dummies.Count; j++)
{
    mySheet.Range[myRange].Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
}
```

Nothing too Earth shattering there.

However, if one of the rows below the insert has a different height to the other rows, what seems to happen is that the new row at that position keeps the same height, and so does the row which is shifted down.

So for example, before the code is run, all rows are normal height except 11 which is double the height of the others.

If I insert 10 rows at row 7, the result is that rows 11 and 21 are double height.

Inserting 1 row above makes 11 and 12 double height.

Inserting 2 rows gives the same result for rows 11 and 13, etc.

So the original double-height row always seems to keep its height, even though the height also follows the shifted-down row.

Is there a way I can specify that when I insert a row, the row height should not get left behind?

[edit]
If I insert a row manually it all works fine.
[/edit]

Comment: Have you tried setting the [NamedRange.RowHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.rowheight.aspx) variable?

Comment: Yes, I can correct the row height that way. Unfortunately I won't necessarily know which rows are being affected each time.

Comment: What about creating a blank row and inserting that instead of using `Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown`?

Comment: I thought that was what the `.Insert` method does. Ok thanks I'll investigate inserting an explicitly defined row.

Comment: I can't seem to find how to do that. Also I don't think it will solve the problem as the rows inserted aren't necessarily the faulty ones.

Comment: there should be a property you can access for the formatting, I'm not at all well versed in C, but possibly something along the lines of `Excel.XlInsertCopyOrigin.xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove`

Answer (score 0):

I found out why this is.

In the code above I'm not shifting the entire row down.

This means that the cells that aren't shifting down are keeping their original height, which is affecting the height of all the other cells in the row.

The following works:

```
for (var j = 0; j < dummies.Count; j++)
{
    mySheet.Range[myRange].EntireRow.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
}
```